# Type conversion of objects involving unsigned type in C language

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have been reading KnR lately and have come across a statement:

> "Type conversions of Expressions involving unsigned type values are
>   complicated"

So to understand this i have written a very small code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    signed char x = -1;
    printf("Signed : %d\n",x);
    printf("Unsigned : %d\n",(unsigned)x);
}
```

- signed x bit form will be : 1000 0001 = -1
- when converted to unsigned its value has to be 1000 0001 = 129.
  But even after type conversion it prints the -1.

> Note: I'm using gcc compiler.

Comment: This behavior is rather uninteresting as `%d` means "treat whatever I pass to printf as a signed int". And also, since printf is variadic function, there is an implicit type promotion of the passed parameter to `int`, if the parameter is a small type.

Comment: Personal advise: burn K&R with fire, then read [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules).

Comment: @Lundin, Then admit that was a bad idea and purchase two more copies to allow for one more lapse of judgement ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba If you want, we can play the game where you pick one random page in K&R. If I can find any typo, incorrect statement, reliance on poorly-defined behavior or blatant violation of C programming de facto good practice, we burn that page. You get to keep what's left. Not even the cover will remain though...

Comment: @Lundin: I'm in. Let's have lunch with Brian first. He tends to come to Oxford in the summer. The question remains though, are we going to use `rand()` to pick the pages?!

Comment: @Bathsheba Alas the page mentioning `rand` (p43) contains the text "The cast operator has the same high precedence as other unary operators, as summarized in the table at the end of this chapter" which is blatantly incorrect and points at the equally incorrect precedence table. See C17 6.5.4 syntax: `cast-expression: unary-expression ( type-name ) cast-expression`.  This was also true in C90, so the book was already incorrect back in 1989. Now I burnt the page containing this misleading information, so we can't use `rand` :(

Answer (score 0):

**C11 6.3.1.3, paragraph 2:**

> Otherwise, if the new type is **unsigned**, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.

`−1` cannot be represented as an `unsigned int` value, the −1 is converted to `UINT_MAX`. Thus `-1` becomes a very large positive integer.

Also, use `%u` for `unsigned int`, otherwise result invoked undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

C semantics regarding conversion of integers is defined in terms of the mathematical values, not in terms of the bits. It is good to understand how values are represented as bits, but, when analyzing expressions, you should think about values.

In this statement:

```
printf("Signed : %d\n",x);
```

the `signed char` `x` is automatically promoted to `int`. Since `x` is −1, the new `int` also has the value −1, and `printf` prints “-1”.

In this statement:

```
printf("Unsigned : %d\n",(unsigned)x);
```

the `signed char` `x` is automatically promoted to `int`. The value is still −1. Then the cast converts this to `unsigned`. The rule for conversion to `unsigned` is that `UINT_MAX+1` is added to or subtracted from the value as needed to bring it into the range of `unsigned`. In this case, adding `UINT_MAX+1` to −1 once brings the value to `UINT_MAX`, which is within range. So the result of the conversion is `UINT_MAX`.

However, this `unsigned` value is then passed to `printf` to be printed with the `%d` conversion. That violates C 2018 7.21.6.1 9, which says the behavior is undefined if the types do not match.

This means a C implementation is allowed to do anything. In your case, it seems what happened is:

- The `unsigned` value `UINT_MAX` is represented with all one bits.
- The `printf` interpreted the all-one-bits value as an `int`.
- Your implementation uses two’s complement for `int` types.
- In two’s complement, an object with all one bits represents −1.
- So `printf` printed “-1”.

If you had used this correct code instead:

```
    printf("Unsigned : %u\n",(unsigned)x);
```

then `printf` would print the value of `UINT_MAX`, which is likely 4,294,967,295, so `printf` would print “4294967295”.